# bin/cowrie: line 121: exec: twistd: not found

Tags: python, python3

I have a problem with Cowrie. Every time I try `bin/cowrie start`, I always get:

```
Join the Cowrie community at: https://www.cowrie.org/slack/

Using activated Python virtual environment "/home/cowrie/cowrie/cowrie-env"

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020.
Cowrie has dropped support for Python 2.7.

Starting cowrie: [twistd  --umask=0022 --pidfile=var/run/cowrie.pid --logger cowrie.python.logfile.logger cowrie ]...
bin/cowrie: line 121: exec: twistd: not found
```

[image: picture here]

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: im using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

- Open the bin/cowrie file with your favorite text editor
- Navigate to line 121 (as indicated by your error message)
- Change twistd to twistd3
- Re-run bin/cowrie start

This worked for me on Kali 2022.2